# AEM - External links appended to current page

Tags: url, append, aem, external, internals

When adding external urls in any component with field, say pagefield or pathfield, it doesnt open the external link, but appends it to the current path

eg: property given - http://www.google.com
when clicked, it goes to
http://localhost:4502/content/wknd/home/us/en/test456/http://www.google.com

is there any setting or config?

Comment: This is highly dependent on your component. If you're using a standard component, can you share this used component and which field you used to add the link? If not, it needs investigation on the component model, the htl and the javascript tied to this component.

Comment: What type of input file are you using?